# AppleScript : use JS with specific Safari WIN/TAB index

Tags: javascript, applescript

I have some issue running JS in a specific safari window/tab

1. the specific safari window and tab are focused with this :

   ```
   set theUrl to "https://www.apple.com"
    tell application "Safari"
        repeat with thisWindow in (every window)
            repeat with thisTab in (every tab of thisWindow whose URL contains theUrl)
                set (current tab of thisWindow) to thisTab
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
   ```

however, when I run the script after (the tab is already focused) but **it doesn't work unless** **I manually click on the specific safari window** (I have a ultra wild minitor with a few safari window displayed)

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('text-entry')[0].value=" & quoted form of myCaseNote in document 1
end tell
```

I also try with this instead, (my initial script to find the tab and window) and try to refer to tab y and window x :

```
    tell application "Safari"
        --Variables
        set windowCount to number of windows
        set docText to ""
        --Repeat for Every Window
        repeat with x from 1 to windowCount
            set tabcount to number of tabs in window x
            --Repeat for Every Tab in Current Window
            repeat with y from 1 to tabcount
                --Get Tab Name & URL
                set tabName to name of tab y of window x
                set tabURL to URL of tab y of window x
                if tabURL contains "https://acmp.corp.apple.com" then
                    tell application "Safari"
                        tell window x
                            
                            set current tab to tab y
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end if
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell


tell application "Safari"
                set myLogOutMessage to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('logout-message')[0].innerHTML;" in tab y of window x
            end tell
```

but I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
set theUrl to "https://www.apple.com"
tell application "Safari"
    repeat with thisWindow in every window
        repeat with thisTab in (every tab of thisWindow whose URL contains theUrl)
            set current tab of thisWindow to thisTab
            tell thisTab
                set myLogOutMessage to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('logout-message')[0].innerHTML;"
            end tell
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```